# What is the opposite of "parallel"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Because of its length, the two towers of the Verrazano Bridge are not parallel: they are [???], accounting for the curvature of the earth.

There's a bunch of terms that come close, such as:

> ***Radial*** from the center of the earth.

Okay, but this only covers vertical lines.

> They're ***skewed***.

Close, but no cigar. "These two lines are skewed." Huh?

Is there an exact term?

[image]